# Draw connecting line to points with a zero ordinate on a log scale with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

Is it possible to plot the connecting line to points whose y value is zero on a log scale in matplotlib?

I have some data that I want to plot with a log scale on the y-axis. The y values for some of the data lie at zero. I realize it's not possible for matplotlib to plot these points on a log scale, but I really wish it would draw the connecting line from the previous point or to the next point (if either are non-zero).

One solution would be to simply replace all zeros with some TINY number. I'd rather not do this.

What matplotlib draws:
[image: Log Plot with No Connecting Line]

What I'd like it to draw:
[image: Log Plot with Connecting Line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be looking to solve this by using the '[`symlog`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale)' option on the y axis instead of '`log`'.  There's then a `linthreshy` arg which lets you specify

> "The range within which the plot is linear (to avoid having the plot
>   go to infinity around zero).".

In fact it's exactly this sort of issue the option seems designed to deal with.  It can look a bit goofy having this weird linear zone along the bottom of your log scale plot, but you can make it pretty small.

Comment: Perfect! It works fine if I just use the symlog option, but for some reason if I try to specify an argument to linthresy I get a `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'`

Answer (score 0):

You could always appened an extra point to the bottom of the graph by pulling out the coordinates from your current figure:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Create some sample data like yours
X = np.linspace(0,3,100)
Y = np.exp(-X)

def semilogy_to_bottom(X,Y):
    # Plot once to move axes and remove plot
    P, = plt.semilogy(X,Y)
    plt.gca().lines.remove(P)

    # Find the bottom of the graph
    y_min = plt.gca().get_ylim()[0]

    # Add a new point
    X2 = np.concatenate((X,[X[-1]]))
    Y2 = np.concatenate((Y,[y_min]))
    plt.semilogy(X2,Y2)

semilogy_to_bottom(X,Y)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

[image]